# Looking for a word that means to get over something

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

Is there a word for when someone has gotten over or is no longer affected by something?

Like after a break up, when someone “moves on” it might mean they have effectively forgotten about the other person. Is there a single word this?

Comment: *recovered* as in *I have fully recovered from Jennifer*?  If that doesn't appeal give us a sample sentence or two into which you want the as-yet undiscovered single word to fit.

Comment: You're *over* it?

Comment: You have overcome it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single word in total, but the phrase 'have closure' might be what you're looking for.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/closure

In the sentence being reviewed, it could look like:

I have closure around what happened with Jennifer

or

They broke up two years ago, but she didn't have closure until six months ago. And then she started dating again.

Answer (score 0):

“Overcome” is the first thing that comes to mind

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The trouble with *overcome* is that the sentence *I have overcome Jennifer* does not mean *I have got over Jennifer*, rather it means something like *I have come off better in my struggle (probably physical, possibly metaphorical) with Jennifer*.